# CSS no me toma las clases que pongo en HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo una consulta con HTML y CSS. Quiero centrar mi menu y logo en css y ponerlo en position fixed pero css no me toma las clases correctamente. Quiero saber si capaz yo estoy poniendo algo de forma incorrecta.
Desde ya muchas gracias!
Este sería el codigo de html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Alex Saberi</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="Photographs, photography, fotografia, 
    camara reflex">
    <meta name="author" content="Alex">
    <meta name="copyright" content="Alex">
    <meta name="robots" content="index">
    <link rel="icon" href="camara.icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="probemos.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="normalize.css">

</head>

<body>
      <header>
        <div class="logo">
          <img id="imagenlogo" alt="Logo profesional" 
           src="https://www.alexsaberi.com/wp- 
           content/uploads/2020/04/logo5.png">
         </div>
      <div class="barras">
    
          <nav class="nav">
            <ul class="barra-ul">
                <li class="bio"><a class="link" href="parte2.html" 
                target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="bio"><a class="link" href="parte3.html" 
                 target="_blank">Photographs</a></li>
                <li class="bio"><a class="link" href="parte4.html" 
                 target="_blank">Works</a></li>
                <li class="bio"><a class="link" href="parte5.html" 
                 target="_blank">Bio</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
         </div>
```

y este en CSS:

```
 #imagenlogo .barra-ul{
    height: 150px;
    background: #262626;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 12;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: georgia;
    }
```

Comment: Y esta clase `.barra-ul` donde está?

Comment: Me equivoque y no la puse en la publicación, ya la agregue sería <ul class="barra-ul">

Comment: ¿Y no estará algún estilo de terceros sobrescribiendo los tuyos? Añade tu `<head>` para descartar esta opción.

Comment: Es que no tiene sentido que si quieres a 2 elementos que son la imagen y el menú en posición `fixed`, entonces le des ese posicionamiento a la etiqueta `img`, sobre todo por que ese selector no parece estar correcto, me parece que será mas simple con aplicar esos estilos pero a la etiqueta `header`

Comment: Finalmente, he encontrado una posible razón, ese `imagenlogo` no tiene ningún `ul` ¿Has querido decir `#imagenlogo, .barra-ul`?

Comment: Probé con header y me tomo los cambios. Muchas gracias! También me fije que yo no ponía una coma cuando usaba id y class en css así que seguramente por eso no me tomaba las cosas

Answer (score 1):

Como te menciono en los comentarios, el selector que estas usando no es correcto, puedes leer mas al respecto [aqui sobre *selectores descendientes*](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator); pues la imagen no tiene como descendiente a `.barra-ul`.

Entonces igualmente como te mencionaba si lo que deseas es que tanto el logo como el menú tengan un posicionamiento `fixed`, entonces sería mas simple darle esa instrucción a la etiqueta padre de ambos que sería el `header`.

Quedando así:

```
header{
    height: 150px;
    background: #262626;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 12;
    position: fixed;
    font-family: georgia;
    }
```

**Comentarios finales**

- Igual el logo puede quedar como elemento directo del menú, ya con *flexbox* puedes desplazar los items y que tenga la presentación deseada
- La etiqueta [**`nav`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements#elementos) es un elemento en bloque, entonces se me hace un *tanto innecesario* que exista dentro de un `div`
- Te recomiendo apliques alguna metodología a tu CSS, puedes investigar sobre **BEM** eso puede beneficiar incluso que mas fácilmente des semántica a tus clases

Answer (score 0):

Tu selector css es `#imagenLogo .barra-ul` y eso haria referencia a un  elemento HTML que contenga la clase `class="barra-ul"` y que a su vez se encuentre dentro de otro elemento que contenga el id `id="imagenLogo"`. Cosa que no existe en tu codigo, porque ese elemento no se encuentra dentro del otro.

Una posible solucion seria cambiar el selector `#imagenLogo .barra-ul` por `#imagenLogo, .barra-ul` (la diferencia esta en poner una coma).

U otra posible solucion seria envolver todo los elementos lo que necesitas en `position: fixed` dentro de un div y en el css seleccionar este elemento y aplicarle la propiedad `position: fixed`.